# Generalized programming for returning the element of a nearest to val

Tags: java

Need to implement the methods of a class much like java.util.Collections – a
library class with static methods designed to provide useful functionality on general Collections of elements. I know how to do this if they are integer elements. Now I need to transform the code into generalized type. Any help will be much appreciated!

From:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public final class Selector {

  private Selector() {
  } 

  public static int nearest(int[] a, int val) {
      if (a == null || a.length == 0) {
         throw new IllegalArgumentException("a is null or has zero-length");
      }
      int idx = 0;
      int distance = Math.abs(a[0]-val);
      for (int c = 1; c < a.length; c++) {
         int cdistance = Math.abs(a[c] - val);
         if (cdistance <= distance) {
            idx = c;
            distance = cdistance;
         }
      }
      int theNumber = a[idx];
      return theNumber;
   }

}
```

to

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

public final class Selector {
  private Selector() { }

  public static <T> T nearest(Collection<T> c, T val, Telemeter<T> tm) {
   .
   .
   .
  }
}
```

Telemeter

```
import java.util.Comparator;

public interface Telemeter<E> extends Comparator<E> {
  double distance(E e1, E e2);
}
```

Comment: Are you needing to do this for production or for school?

Comment: What you're doing is actually the same thing that `sort()` method in `Collections` does

Comment: This is part of homework. Any hints will be highly appreciated!

Comment: You haven't shown us what `Telemeter` does; I presume it gives you some sort of user-defined "distance" between two `T`s. In that case, you just need to take the code in your array-based `nearest`, update the `for` loop with an `Iterator` over `c`, and use `tm` instead of the minus operation.

Comment: By generalize type , you mean flat double or String etc?

Comment: My bad! Just updated it.

Comment: I think it should be any type.

Comment: Added an answer based on some assumption, hope you would be able to carry on from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your existing code, if you may want to convert it into generic, the code would look similar to below:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public final class Selector {

  private Selector() {
  } 

  public static <T> T nearest(Collection<T> c, T val, Telemeter<T> tm) {
      if (c == null || c.isEmpty()) {
         throw new IllegalArgumentException("a is null or has zero-length");
      }
      int idx = 0;
      double distance = tm.distance(c.get(0), val);
      for (int i = 1; i < c.size(); i++) {
         double cdistance = tm.distance(c.get(i), val);
         if (cdistance <= distance) {
            idx = i;
            distance = cdistance;
         }
      }
      int theNumber = c.get(idx);
      return theNumber;
   }

}
```